# "day of month must be between 1 and last day of month" when looking for time in Oracle

Tags: mysql, date, datetime

This may be rather simple, but i just don't get how to fix this.

So this is rather a simple query i'm doing:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(DATE,'DD-MM-YYYY') AS DATE, TO_CHAR(TIME,'HH24:MI') AS TIME,
CODEROOM, GROUP0, GROUP1, GROUP2, GROUP3,
FROM CONCERTS
WHERE DATE = '20-05-16' AND TIME = '00:00'  AND CODEROOM = '1'
```

Now, if i do the exact same query removing  "AND TIME = '00:00'", everything works completely fine, but if i try to search for TIME, it throws the following error:

```
01847. 00000 -  "day of month must be between 1 and last day of month"
```

I know i can group in the same column TIME and DATE, and i tried and i did not manage to fix it either.

I seriously don't know how to fix that, i know it can be because DATEs in Oracle store DATE and TIME, and it could have an invalid DATE despite having an okay time, but if that was the case, the error would be thrown when executing the query, and i can't even get to execute it (I also checked the dates were valid anyway)

Is there any way to fix this? i've been looking up and i can't seem to find a solution to this

Thanks a lot in advance :)

Comment: arent `DATE`  and `TIME`  reserved words? I mean if you use  `D`  and `T`  have same error? because usually you cant use the Alias from a `SELECT` on the `WHERE`

Comment: BTW: What are you trying to do with your query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, You may first want to change your column definitions so that you have meaningful name such as `CONCERT_DATE` or `CONCERT_TIME`

Second, You would need to apply the same to_char function on your where clause as 
well..

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(DATE,'DD-MM-YYYY') AS CONCERT_DATE, TO_CHAR(TIME,'HH24:MI') AS CONCERT_TIME,
CODEROOM, GROUP0, GROUP1, GROUP2, GROUP3,
FROM CONCERTS
WHERE TO_CHAR(DATE,'DD-MM-YYYY') = '20-05-2016' 
  AND TO_CHAR(TIME,'HH24:MI') = '00:00'  
  AND CODEROOM = '1'
```

Answer (score 1):

As I explain in my comment you can't use the alias in the where. You need copy the function as @cableload did or use a subquery

```
SELECT *
FROM (
       SELECT To_char(date, 'DD-MM-YYYY') AS D, 
              To_char(time, 'HH24:MI')    AS T, 
              coderoom, 
              group0,  group1, 
              group2,  group3, 
       FROM   concerts 
       WHERE  coderoom = '1' 
     ) foo
WHERE  foo.D = '20-05-2016' -- here you had YY instead of YYYY
  AND  foo.T = '00:00'
```

And dont use reserved word like `DATE` or `TIME`  as alias/fieldname

Comment: Yeah, the alias was because it was in spanish and i translated it to english quickly, my bad on that. @cableload's fix worked  wonders, thanks for everything!

Comment: I know cableload work, I just want to show you other way to handle this issue. Some time the function are to complex to copy again and use the subquery produce a clean code and easier to read

Comment: You are right, this would be a big issue in bigger cases, i think i'll try this one instead, thanks so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Your date literals need to be in [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Calendar_dates) format, that is `'2016-05-20'` rather than  `'20-05-16'`.

Comment: He already format the string to `'DD-MM-YYYY'` But compare to `'DD-MM-YY`, but that should be string comparation. The problems is something else